# UWP cross threading info

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

The last few days I have been working on updating a UI control from another thread and I thought I had it down with the Progress<> object.

Im running into a little issue with my Streamsocket TCP server project.  I have everything up and running but I can't seem to figure out how to pass my data string back to my main UI.

Here is the jest of my program (when the client connects fire the event handler)

```
StreamSocketListener server = new StreamSocketListener();

server.ConnectionReceived += ClientConnection;

private async void ClientConnection(StreamSocketListener Client, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {



        while (true)
        {
```

The issue is i cant pass the ClientConnection Event Handler my Progress<> object.
I have spent the last few days trying to figure out another way to do it but nothing seems to work.  Anyone have any ideas?  I would really appreciate it.

Comment: you code snipplet is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snipplet is incomplete. 
Usually you follow the MVVM pattern - then the update of the control is done outside your code via NotifyPropertyChanged on the binded variable.